# how to pass a function that has argument to a customwidget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a custom widget of slider widget where there is a function of onChange

I dont know how to pass this function to a custom widget as it has argument

its easy to pass when a function is without argument

like

final VoidCallBack ontap;

```
class CustomSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  final double value;
// how to pass voidcallback with argument here
  const CustomSlider({Key? key,required this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfSlider.vertical(
      min: 50,
      max: 250.0,
      value: value,
      interval: 20,
      showTicks: true,
      showLabels: true,
      enableTooltip: true,
      minorTicksPerInterval: 1,
      onChanged: (dynamic value) {
// how to deal with this function
      },
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a function with arguments to a custom widget in Flutter, you can define a function type as a parameter in your custom widget.

In your case, since the **onChanged** function takes a dynamic value as an argument and returns void, you can define it as follows in your **CustomSlider** widget:

```
typedef ValueChanged<T> = void Function(T value);

class CustomSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  final double value;
  final ValueChanged<dynamic>? onChanged;

  const CustomSlider({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider(
      value: value,
      min: 50,
      max: 250.0,
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        if (onChanged != null) {
          onChanged!(newValue);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Now, when you use **CustomSlider**, you can pass a function to the **onChanged** parameter:

```
CustomSlider(
  value: _sliderValue,
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _sliderValue = newValue;
    });
  },
)
```

In this example, **_sliderValue** is a state variable that gets updated whenever the slider value changes. The **setState** call ensures that the widget rebuilds with the new slider value. Note that you may want to make sure that the function you pass to onChanged expects a parameter of the type that the Slider will emit (probably a double in this case).

Comment: Thanks...For ur breif answer....this is what i wanted...upvote if my question is helpful to others..

Comment: Happy to know that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
final ValueSetter<int> onChanged; 
//typedef ValueSetter<in T> = void Function(T value)
```

OR

```
final void Function(int) onChanged;
```

if need back value:

```
final String Function(int) onChanged;
```